# Point2D.Double in C#

Tags: java, c#

In Java, I have the following code snippet:

```
public static double absoluteBearing(Point2D.Double source, Point2D.Double target) {
    return Math.atan2(target.x - source.x, target.y - source.y);
}
```

I would like to know how to work with "Point2D.Double" in C #.

Comment: I'm not C# expert, but this looks like a question better solved by searching an API which for C# I think is the MSDN. Maybe [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/618ayhy6.aspx) is the link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows Forms, you can use the [`PointF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pointf.aspx) struct. (Note, that this uses a `float` internally as the name suggests, but is usually enough precision.)

In WPF, you can use the [`Point`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.point%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) struct.

Assuming you are using WinForms (As it is most similar to Swing in Java), your code would translate to:

```
public static double absoluteBearing(PointF source, PointF target) {
    return Math.Atan2(target.Y - source.Y, target.X - source.X);
}
```

Note that X and Y are inverted in C#'s `Atan2`.

Comment: Sure, but in another method I return one `Point2D.Double`, as shown below (all parameters are passed on double):

    `return new Point2D.Double (loc.x + distance * Math.sin (heading), loc.y + distance * Math.cos (heading));`

However, the parameters of the `Point` and the `PointF` are respectively `int` and `float`. To cast the types will be the only solution?

Comment: Yes, WinForms does not have a double version, although it would be easy to write one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you use WPF then you can get a **double-precision** `Point` which much more closely matches the original Java `Point2D.Double`.

```
public static double absoluteBearing(Point source, Point target) 
{
    return Math.atan2(target.X - source.X, target.Y - source.Y);
}
```

This does not necessarily mean your app has to be converted to WPF.

[Point structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Point(v=vs.110).aspx)